# Firebase limit update to a custom field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In Firebase, here is my Firestore :

[image]

I am using this function to Update Like :

```
 const docRef = await doc(db, "databasetest", "explaura");
           const Path = `${_Selected.Name}.Like`;
            await updateDoc(docRef, {
                [Path]: increment(1)
            });
```

So _Selected.Name is Dynamic (Reference as DynamicName on the screen Shot).

How can I create a Firebase rules to allow ONLY like Update ? Found solution with `request.resource.data.keys().hasAll` but it's not Working. I can Update all child of DynamicName or none, but not Only "Like"

Can you help me please ?

I also Tried something like that :

```
match /databasetest/explaura/{id}{
      allow read: if true;
      allow update: if (request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(['Like']));
    }
```

Comment: The rule looks okay as per Firebase' documentation. have you tested making allow update false or removing it and seeing if it the rule gets read/executed?

Comment: Yeah, without the rule it's working but the rule is not working the way I want. Maybe because the key is note just "Like" but "DynamicName.Like" ?

Comment: You could also try diff(resource.data.DynamicName)....

Comment: DynamicName change everytime, it's a Name (Jean, James...) How can I use this ? Should is use something like `{name}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All methods of [`rules.MapDiff`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff) return a [`rules.Set`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Set) which does not contain an index operator, like [`rules.List`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List) does. This prevents using `diff` for your purpose (I have created a ticket to Firebase like 2 years ago to have this added to the API but haven't got any news since, feel free to create one yourself).

Fortunatly there is a deprecated property `request.writeFields` that you can use and that fits your need. It contains all the fields that have been changed (updated, created, deleted):

```
match /databasetest/explaura/{id}{
  allow read: if true;
  allow update: if request.writeFields.size() == 1  // Only one field is updated
    && validate_update();

  function validate_update() {
    let fields = request.writeFields[0].split('\\.');  // In your case request.writeFields should be equal to ['DynamicName.like']
    return fields.size() == 2    // ['DynamicName','like']
      && fields[0].size() <= 30  // Some condition on DynamicName
      && fields[1] == 'like'     // Only field updated is 'like'
      && request.resource.data.get(fields, 0) = 1 + resource.data.get(fields, 0) // We only accept increment, modify as you wish
  }
}
```

Here I use the version of [rules.Map.get](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map#get) accepting an array as parameter to retrieve nested fields.

Notes:

1. `request.writeFields` is deprecated but still working, use at your own risk.
2. My guess is that it has been deprecated because its behavior can be a bit weird in some edge cases, especially for nested fields.
3. Still, I find it crazy to mark something as deprecated when there is no new solution offering the same functionality (heads up to the firebaser here...)

Comment: thanks for you help ! I'll check that ASAP

I found another "solution" (not fully working for the moment) : 

`match /databasetest/explaura{
      allow read: if true;
      allow update: if CheckUpdate();
    }
 }`
  
 `function CheckUpdate() {
 let Arr = ["Puy de la tache", "Banne d'ordanche"];
      let Name = (request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).addedKeys()).split('.')[0];
      return request.resource.data[Arr[0]].diff(resource.data[Arr[0]]).changedKeys() == ['Like'].toSet();
 }`

Comment: That cannot work, `addedKeys` returns a `rules.Set` which does not have a `split` method

Comment: Oh okey, thanks for this precision ! Really Helpfull ! And I don't want to manually add every key..

Your code Seams to Work, thank you so much ! Hope writeFields won't be remove